# Plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> I write article.

> I write articles.

**Update:**

I should have provided this information beforehand. Why my confusion arises as I was doing the passive voice.

Now, what meaning I want to  express, *There is an author, who just want to express that, I am an author and I generally write articles.* So as per the grammar point of view this can be put as `Simple Present Tense`. Now, the most appropriate sentence for this would be,

**Set-1**

> *Active voice:* I write articles.
>
> *Passive voice:* Articles are written by me.

Which also I think retains the meaning.

Now if I take the following sentence and its passive voice,

**Set-2**

> *Active voice:* I write an article.
>
> *Passive voice:* An article is written by me.

So, if I analyze the expression of passive voice, it expresses like, Just one article is written by me. It does not express that I am an author who generally writes the article.

So, I should again check the following sentence,

**Set-3**

> *Active voice:* I write article.
>
> *Passive voice:* Article is written by me.

Now, in above set, the active voice is providing the meaning that, I am an Author, and I write article. while its passive voice is not providing that meaning.

So, I am assuming that, Both voices should provide the same expression(If this is not true kindly let me know), and if I compare all three above sets, and from your answers its looks like `I write articles.` are most appropriate as its both, Active and Passive voice expressing the same meaning. But still I am in confusion as English is my second language so I cannot properly understand the expression. Hence, which one would be the proper suits here? Very very thanks.

Comment: I think your update makes the question a different question. In other words, it's asking about a different thing. Previously, the question seemed to ask whether using *article* (without a definite or an indefinite article) or using *articles* is correct. Now, the question seems to focus on the passive voice. -- FWIW, none of the passive voice sentences sound good. We don't deliver information that way in English in this kind of context. If you want to use the passive voice appropriately and effectively, I suggest reading more books, articles, papers, etc. that are written in a good style.

Comment: @DamkerngT. at first place it thought to ask which one is correct in context of simple present tense in the title but it was edited and title was changed to something totally different. I thought if I get the correct active voice, then passive voice will automatically correct, but after reading all answer and further thinking I thought that it I should have provided more information, hence added updates. Although, thank for details, it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is right. In the first sentence, you should say "I write an article" or "I write the article".

Answer (score 1):

You can say *I write articles*, but with *article* you need to use *an*/*the* before.

> I write an article.

That is not influenced from the tense being used, since it is so with every tense.

> I wrote an article.

> I should write an article.

> I have written an article.

Comment: Thanks, I should have provided more information, in question. As you already answered `I write articles.` would be more appropriate. I have updated the question, please let me if any change after reading the update. Sorry for inconvenience, I should have provided that information beforehand. Very thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I write article.

I write articles.

The former isn't grammatucal; article is a countable noun that needs the indefinite article "an" in front of it.  So you say:

I write an article.

The latter is grammatical; you can say either "I write an article" or "I write articles", but the latter is more commin.

A- What do you do for a living.

B- I write articles.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it seems like `I write articles.` are appropriate. Please kindly see the Updated question, actually I should put that information prior, but after observing all answers, I thought I should provide the Update. Please let me know if it is different that `I write articles` after reading the update. Very thanks.